# Flask: Storing Socket-Connection variables without Cookies

Tags: python, sockets, flask, server, flask-socketio

I need to have 'variables and activity associated with each client' without using cookies. How and where can i store this variables? I am pretty new to flask and servers.
For now, I thought of using a python dictionary and storing sessionID-variable pairs like shown below.
I have a feeling that this is a stupid idea, but I can not think of an alternative :/.
Hope, you can help me.

```
import flask  

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'
enter code heresocketio = SocketIO(app)

cache = {}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return send_from_directory('static', "index.html")

@socketio.on('savePseudonym')
def sendKeepAlive(): 
    cache[(request.sid,'pseudonym')]= pseudonym
    cache[(request.sid,'time')]= time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `session`, in more or less the same way you use it with Flask routes.

```py
from flask import session

@socketio.on('savePseudonym')
def sendKeepAlive(): 
    session['pseudonym'] = pseudonym
    session['time'] = time
```

The only thing to keep in mind is that because Socket.IO sessions are not based on cookies, any changes you make to the session in a Socket.IO handler will not appear on the Flask session cookie. If you need to share the session between Flask routes and Socket.IO event handlers, then you can use a server-side session with the Flask-Session extension.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! When using the 'session' with SocketIO I could not find any cookies saved in the browser of the clients. Is this 'session' only stored on the server when it is used with SocketIO or was I just too dumm to find it in the browser's memory?

Comment: The session is always stored server-side for Socket.IO. It's actually stored in memory.

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you so much! Let's say the connection is disconnected at some point. Is the information of the client deleted or is there a way to cache the data in case the client reconnects?

Comment: The user session goes away when the client disconnects. The application needs to restore this information when the client reconnects.